# Need To Open my specific path Using OpenFileDialog of C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, visual-studio-2013

for suppose 
When i use OpenFIleDialog.show() in general it Opens by default to Documents.
but i want to change that to mygiven path c:\project\

so when i do  OpenFIleDialog.show()  it must defaultly open to C:\project\

how can i achieve this

Comment: As is often the case, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the initialdirectory property.

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\project";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use InitiaDirectory property of the OpenFileDialog before call the show method.